# Fontforge generate webfont

Tags: webfonts

i want to generate a webfont using fontforge on windows. Have anyone tried it? I have installed a font forge but the TOOLS menu are disabled. I need to install something but i dont know what and how to enable the export as webfont option.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Macbook. When generating fonts, output file type is available when you did draw or import some glyphs. You need to generate ttf, svg, woff and eot to support different browsers.

There is another choice. Some online font generators are easy to use. Try http://iconfont.cn/.